# What is HADR SEEDING TEST database in High availability server, in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, alwayson

Our servers belongs to Always On Availability Group. In both node we could see a database like "HADR SEEDING TEST"  has been created in our server.

- We don't know when was it created.
- How is it getting created and what is it?
- Will it make any error if we drop this db?

Thanks,

Julie

Comment: [The Availability Group Wizard and the HADR Seeding Test Database](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-availability-group-wizard-and-the-hadr-seeding-test-database/)

Comment: Hi Julie, if you found a good answer, please answer your own question, maybe you will have to wait for some time due to your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I could find an answer for this question.

The db "HADR Seeding Test " will get created when creating an Availability Group in SQL Server 2012 using the New Availability Group Wizard in SQL Server Management Studio.

Please refer the below link

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/the-availability-group-wizard-and-the-hadr-seeding-test-database/

Thanks,

Julie